# Data is not getting printed sequentially in the order after calling an API inside the for each loop using fork join in rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

On trying to call the API inside the for each loop using fork join the data is not getting printed in the desired order i.e API response for the 2nd iteration gets printed first, 2nd iteration gets printed and so on. As I am a bit new to RXJS I am not sure how to go forward with this.

Below is the code that I have tried:

```
datesList = ['01-12-2022', '05-12-2022', '07-12-2022']  

this.datesList.forEach(item => {
  forkJoin(this.APIService.getDataFromDateslist(item)) 
    .subscribe(([data]) => {
      console.log("response data", data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Using API calls is asynchronous and the results aren't guaranteed to be in the same order without `await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are using 3 different `forkJoin` with one item each, rather than a single `forkJoin` with 3 items.

Your current code is equivalent to this:

```js
forkJoin(this.APIService.getDataFromDateslist(item[0]).subscribe();
forkJoin(this.APIService.getDataFromDateslist(item[1]).subscribe();
forkJoin(this.APIService.getDataFromDateslist(item[2]).subscribe();
```

You need to effectively do:

```js
forkJoin([
    this.APIService.getDataFromDateslist(item[0]),
    this.APIService.getDataFromDateslist(item[1]),
    this.APIService.getDataFromDateslist(item[2]),
]).subscribe();
```

You can achieve this like so:

```js
datesList = ['01-12-2022', '05-12-2022', '07-12-2022'];
apiCalls = this.datesList.map(date => this.APIService.getDataFromDateslist(date));

forkJoin(apiCalls).subscribe();
```